# Checking if a given string is #define in C

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I am trying to check if a given string is #define:
**EDIT:**
I am reading a text file which contains a list of token names and text to be copied, line per line then checking if the token name read in the file is already #define. If the token is defined then the "copy text" under it will be copied in a string in the program. If not then it will skip the "copy text". 
The code below is just a snippet of how I was checking the token name if it is defined:

```
#define TOKEN_A 1
#define TEST_1(x) x

int main(){

    char *str = "TOKEN_A";
    #ifdef TEST_1(str)
    printf("TOKEN_A is Defined!\n");
    #else
    printf("TOKEN_A is not Defined!\n");
    #endif

    char *str1 = "TOKEN_B";
    #ifdef TEST_1(str1)
    printf("TOKEN_B is Defined!\n");
    #else
    printf("TOKEN_B is not Defined!\n");
    #endif
}
```

Text file sample contents:

```
 TOKEN_A
 copy text
 TOKEN_B
 copy text
```

Both #ifdef result is true, even though TOKEN_B is not defined.
OUTPUT:

```
"TOKEN_A is Defined!"
"TOKEN_B is Defined!"
```

I was wondering if my checking is wrong.
Is there any other way to check a string if it is #define?
Thanks

Comment: Pretty sure that all this does is check whether `TEST_1` is defined.

Comment: What can I do so that it process the value of TEST_1 instead?

Comment: You can say `#ifdef TOKEN_A`

Comment: Is there any other way?
Because I placed the token name into a string so that I can be able to change it during runtime.
So that I can dynamically check a string if it is define.

Comment: The problem is that the #define and the #ifdef don't exist at runtime. They only exist during compile time.

Comment: I see, so I can't use #ifdef when checking tokens dynamically.

Do you have any suggestions to check #define with out using #ifdef

Comment: I think you need to describe the actual problem that you're trying to solve. Why does the program need to know if there was a `#define TOKEN_A`?

Comment: I have edited my post and added additional description. Thank you!

Comment: [The Toggle that Wouldn't](https://thedailywtf.com/articles/The-Toggle-that-Wouldnt)

Comment: You would need an array of strings, e.g. `char *allowed[] = { "TOKEN_A", "TOKEN_C", "TOKEN_J" };` Then after reading a control line from the input file, you would use `strcmp` in a loop to see if that line is in the `allowed` array.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica my problem is that the token name is not fixed which will be used in #ifdef. the token name is from a text file, so i can't straightly write `#ifdef TOKEN_A `.

Comment: @mav The point of that story is that `#ifdef` only works for things that are fixed at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

It is not realistically practical to do that. The reason is that `#define` is a preprocessor directive, and will not exist during the runtime. It disappears upon preprocessor's passing of preprocessed code to the main body of the c compiler.